# Swing drawing sometimes works

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to draw functions using Java Swing and AWT. The problem is not always all of the 300 points of the graph are drawn. When I loop over the first points of the graph in debug mode, there is much more change the graph is drawn completely. I use the following code to create a `JFrame` and set the graphics object to the class member g.

```
jFrame = new JFrame();
jFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
jFrame.setVisible(true);
g = jFrame.getContentPane().getGraphics();
```

Then I call this method for every function I want to draw.

```
private void drawGraph(IGraph graph, Bounds bounds, Ratios ratios) {
    //contains visual information about the graph
    GraphVisuals visuals = graph.getVisuals();
    g.setColor(visuals.color);
    //the previous point is remembered, to be able to draw a line from one point to the next
    int previousXi = 0;
    int previousYi = 0;
    //a loop over every point of the graph. The graph object contains two arrays: the x values and the y values
    for (int i = 0; i < graph.getSize(); ++i) {
        //calculate the x value using the ratio between the graph's size on the x-axis and the window size and the starting point on the x-axis
        int xi = (int) (ratios.xRatio * (graph.getX(i) - bounds.xMin) + 0.5);
        //analogous for the y axis
        int yi = HEIGHT - (int) (ratios.yRatio * (graph.getY(i) - bounds.yMin) + 0.5);
        //draw
        if (visuals.hasBullets) {
           g.fillOval(xi, yi, visuals.bulletSize, visuals.bulletSize);
        }
        if (visuals.hasLine) {
            if (i != 0) {
                g.drawLine(previousXi, previousYi, xi, yi);
            }
        }
        previousXi = xi;
        previousYi = yi;
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this: `g = jFrame.getContentPane().getGraphics();`. Create a new `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent(Graphics)` method, call `super.paintComponent(Graphics)` and do the drawing there. If that doesn't help you, please consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).